# Как создать новость в категории DLE?

Tags: html, dle, data-life-engine

Как создать новость в категории DLE? я создал категорию `Партнеры`, но не могу туда добавить новость, добавил код в `about-nav.tpl`

```
<li><a href="/partners.html" class="link nav__item <? if(($_GET['page']=='partners')){echo 'active';}?>"><?php echo _("Партнеры");?></a></li>
```

но при добавлении новости, на странице ничего не появляется

Answer (score 0):

В DLE вывод своих шаблонов выводится на странице при помощи тега `{custom category="номер категории" template="имя шаблона без расширения .tpl" limit="количество выводимых шаблонов" }`